# Get a constrained list of unique elements from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I have to solve this optimization problem using Python. I have a list of lists, each one containing elements. For instance:

```
l = [
       ['elem1'],
       ['elem2'],
       ['elem3','elem4'],
       ['elem4','elem5']
    ]
```

What I need to obtain is a list `r` such that:

1) Both the lists should have the same length

```
>>> len(r)==len(l)
True
```

2) Each selected element should correspond to the elements of the same index list

```
>>> correct=True
>>> for r_element in r:
...     if r_element not in l[r.index(r_element)]:
...         correct=False
...         break
...         
>>> correct
True
```

3) Elements should be unique

```
>>> len(r) > len(set(r))
False
```

A possible result here will be for example:

```
r = ['elem1','elem2','elem3','elem4']
```

Is there a best way to do this? Or maybe not using lists but some other data structures or some specific Python packages?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: If the elements in `r` are unique then 3) should have been `False` but anyway. Just flatten `l` and remove the duplicate elements

Comment: @Ev.Kounis True, thanks

Comment: @grael no nothing so far

Comment: @adefabritiis What would happen if i reach a list in `l` whose all elements already exist in `r`? Are you sure that all the cases are going to be solvable?

Comment: @adefabritiis Should r just consist of one selected item from each list? Also are the lists in l guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I don't understand your question, I want to create `r` starting from `l` and fullfilling those constraints. If they are not fulfilled, `r` will not exist.

Comment: @gowrath one item from each list and not sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses recursive backtracking to make selections and backtracks if they don't work. The function returns a failure in the form of a string if no list can meet the constraints.

```
l = [
       ['elem1', 'elem5'],
       ['elem2'],
       ['elem3','elem4'],
       ['elem1','elem2']
    ]

def constrained_list(l):
    r = []                # final list
    used = set()          # values used
    if recurse(r, used, l): return r        # if successul in finding contrained list, return it
    return "No valid list"

def recurse(r, used, l):
    if not l: return True       # base case, l has been completely processed
    line = l[0]                 # look at first line in l
    for word in line:
        if word not in used:
            used.add(word)      
            r.append(word)      # try adding this word
            if recurse(r, used, l[1:]): return True     # recurse on the rest of l, from 1 to end
            used.remove(word)   # if this choice didnt work, backtrack.
            r.pop()
    return False
```

This outputs:

```
['elem5', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem1']
```

Comment: replace the last list in `l` with `['elem1', 'elem2']` and run it again. Is criteria no 2 not violated? This is  what i meant in the comment above

Comment: @Ev.Kounis In that case, there is not way to satisfy this right? The assertion error will be raised. An actual error that could happen is if the first element in `l` is `['elem1', 'elem5']` and then the last element is `['elem1', 'elem2']`. In this case the first selection would mess it up, we should've picked `elem5` to be in the first position and `elem1` in the last.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Im gonna delete this; the solution would involve some kind of recursive backtracking and I cba to write it up.

Comment: depending on the size of `l` and the way its items are distributed this might actually be a really hard problem..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Check the solution now. I think this should always find a valid solution if one exists.

Comment: @gowrath Thanks to your approach I modified the algorithm so that `l` can be in this format also 
`l = [
       ['elem1', 'elem5'],
       ['elem2'],
       [['elem1','elem4'],['elem1','elem2']],
       ['elem1','elem3']
    ]`
Now it is possible to force not only one `elem` each row but also more.

Comment: @adefabritiis Good to hear! Take note this will start running pretty slowly on huge inputs.

Comment: @gowrath yes I know, I am looking for some other approaches also, but don't know actually